# Can I allow arbitrary fields in a shared struct?

Tags: go, struct

I would like to define an object in a shared libary,

```
type Common struct {
   field_a string
   custom  interface{}
}
```

where `custom` is expected to hold additional fields that the user of this common object might define in their file, e.g.,

```
// module-1
type Mod1Customs struct {
   abc string
}
```

From here, I would like to be able to set `Common.custom` to `Mod1Customs` so that I can access both `field_a` and `abc` in the same way from within module-1. I would like to do the same thing for other modules that may define an entirely different struct to assign to `custom` though.

The general idea is to create an object of pre-defined defaults and allowing a bucket of sorts for the users of the object to add their own custom fields.

Is this possible?

Comment: *"Is this possible?"* No, it isn't. Interfaces don't expose fields, only methods. Also keep in mind that if you want to share something between packages you need to export it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is embedding:

```
type Common struct {
    FieldA string
}

type Mod1Customs struct {
    Common
    Abc string
}
```

Then Mod1Customs gets access to all of Common fields directly:

```
c := Mod1Customs{}
fmt.Println(c.FieldA)
fmt.Println(c.Abc)
```

See [Embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html?h=embedding#embedding) in Effective Go for more details.

If you have some functions that deal with Common fields (no matter what the struct), then you would implement that with an `interface` that declares the fields you need. `Mod1Customs` would automatically conform to that interface.